# SAP HANA vs Oracle 9/10 and Informix 11

Tags: database, jdbc, hana

I need to import on HANA the data stored on DB Oracle 9-10 and Informix 11. Which is the best practice supported by SAP in order to achieve this target?

Is SAP HANA Smart Data Integration with JDBC the right tool?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a one-time data export/import or an on-going data replication process? Or something in-between? What is the scenario you want to enable? And what version of HANA are you using? The Oracle and Informix DB versions seem ancient.

Comment: It is a one-time data export/import process. HANA is version 2 and considering that HANA 2 doesn't have any compatibility on Oracle 9-10 and Informix my focus is on JDBC. I would avoid the csv file in order to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is a one-time data transfer.
The one option probably best suited for this is the CSV export/import.

It's well supported by all DMBS and is commonly well-optimized in terms of data throughput.

But the OP wrote that this is not the preferred option.

Depending on available licenses, HANA's Smart Data Integration (SDI) feature allows using arbitrary JDBC clients to connect. That could be a viable option.

A caveat here is that data type/precision differences might go unnoticed due to the built-in -JDBC/JDBC- mapping.
Don't get me wrong here. SDI definitively works a treat but data migration never is a click'n'forget thing.

Having worked extensively with both Oracle and HANA (and a little bit with Informix a long time ago), I'd still go with CSV for this one-time effort and use SDI for on-going integration.